# Write to another terminal

Tags: 16.04

I have two terminals opened on my desktop `tty8` and `tty9`. Username `g` is logged in both of them. Trying to send message from `tty9` to `tty8`:

```
g@ubuntu:~$ write g tty8
write: g is not logged in on tty8
```

Why I'm not logged? Where might be problem?

UPD.

`w` command output:
 10:20:28 up  3:26,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00

```
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
g        tty7     :0               06:54    3:26m  1:17   0.20s /sbin/upstart -
```

`tty` command in both terminals prints:

```
/dev/pts/8
```

and

```
/dev/pts/9
```

I was expecting it means `tty8` and  `tty9`

Comment: What does the command `w` return?  It should show all active ttys and users logged in.  [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1002711/edit) your question and add the output of `w`.

Comment: Actually, are you using `gnome-terminal`?  It looks as though there might be a bug with the `gnome-terminal`.  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1280724  I can get it to work on my tests using `xfce4-terminal` and `xterm` without issues, but `gnome-terminal` will not show anything.  I am thinking that the bug is still there.   I just created a bug report for it:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1747198

Comment: One way around it is to `ssh localhost` in each terminal window, then they work fine.

Comment: It actually looks like they are not going to fix it as it was removed.  It was posted to my bug report that I filed yesterday.  How sad.